# VBA Excel macro based on _Chart Activate_ event does not run on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I made a macro that prepares data to build a graph of a personality test. It works as follows:

- **1)** The user fills a form where he or she answers questions using numbers ranging from -10 to 10. The form is in a worksheet called
  *Minha História*.
- **2)** The graph is on the worksheet *Meu Grafico*. When the correspondent tab of *Meu Grafico* is select, the Macro is loaded
  through the *Chart Activate* event.
- **3)** Additionally, the macro adjusts the X-axis of the graph to the data origin, since the quantity of data on the graph varies with the
  age of the user.

**The problem**: This macro runs perfectly on Windows, but when I tried to run it on a Mac computer it failed to run, even when macros are habilitated to the Mac computer.

**What is strange**: In the VBE Project window of the Windows computer I can see that the code is correctly put in the Chart object module called `_Planilha2(Meu Grafico)_`. But on the Mac, the system:

a) ignores that assignment and renames the chart object module to `_Planilha21(Meu Grafico)_`;

b) erases the code in this module and put it in a new module called `_Gr.fico2_` (Why?).

*Obs*: This Macro does not construct the graph. It only made some calculations with the answers in order that they be reflected on the graph. It has to work at any moment the user changes the answer of any question in the form. And, if fact, it do it on the Windows PC, only.

Can anyone can help me with this?

[image]

**Code**:

```
Private Sub Chart_Activate()
'Macro criada por Ramon Barbosa Rosa em 29/10/2018
'SANTÉ COACHING
Dim Dados As Worksheet
Dim Base As Worksheet
Dim j As Integer
Dim Idade As Integer
Dim Coluna As Integer
Set Dados = Worksheets("Minha História")
Set Base = Worksheets("Base")
Idade = -1

'Calcula idade do coachee
For j = 2 To 95
    If Base.Cells(2, j) <> "" Then
    Idade = Idade + 1
    End If
Next j

Coluna = Idade + 2 'Indica o número da coluna do ano corrente

'Apaga valores remanescentes de anos anteriores
Base.Range(Base.Cells(5, Coluna + 1), Base.Cells(5, 100)).ClearContents
Base.Range(Base.Cells(8, Coluna + 1), Base.Cells(8, 100)).ClearContents
Base.Range(Base.Cells(11, Coluna + 1), Base.Cells(11, 100)).ClearContents

'Série PESSOAL: Preenche valor referente ao ano de nascimento
If Base.[b4] = 0 Then
    Base.[b5] = Base.[b3]
Else
    Base.[b5] = Base.[b4]
End If

'Série PESSOAL: preenche demais anos (Planilha Ref, oculta)
For i = 3 To Idade + 2
    If Base.Cells(4, i - 1) > 0 And Base.Cells(4, i) > 0 Then 'Laranja
        Base.Cells(5, i) = Base.Cells(5, i - 1) + Base.Cells(4, i)
    ElseIf Base.Cells(4, i - 1) > 0 And Base.Cells(4, i) < 0 Then 'verde água
        Base.Cells(5, i) = Base.Cells(3, i) + Base.Cells(4, i)
    ElseIf Base.Cells(4, i - 1) <= 0 And Base.Cells(4, i) > 0 Then 'Roxo
        Base.Cells(5, i) = Base.Cells(4, i) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Base.Range(Base.Cells(5, 2), Base.Cells(5, i - 1)))
    ElseIf Base.Cells(4, i - 1) <= 0 And Base.Cells(4, i) < 0 Then 'Azul
        Base.Cells(5, i) = Base.Cells(5, i - 1) + Base.Cells(4, i)
    ElseIf Base.Cells(4, i) = 0 Then 'Rosa
        Base.Cells(5, i) = Base.Cells(3, i)
    End If
Next i

'Série PROFISSIONAL: Preenche valor referente ao ano de nascimento
If Base.[b10] = 0 Then
    Base.[b11] = 0
Else
    Base.[b11] = Base.[10]
End If

'Série PROFISSIONAL: preenche demais anos (Planilha Ref, oculta)
'Considera resultado como igual a zero até a primeira experiência profissional
For i = 3 To Idade + 2
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Base.Range(Base.Cells(10, 2), Base.Cells(10, i))) = 0 Then
        Base.Cells(11, i) = 0
    ElseIf Base.Cells(10, i - 1) > 0 And Base.Cells(10, i) > 0 Then 'Laranja
        Base.Cells(11, i) = Base.Cells(11, i - 1) + Base.Cells(10, i)
    ElseIf Base.Cells(10, i - 1) > 0 And Base.Cells(10, i) < 0 Then 'verde água
        Base.Cells(11, i) = Base.Cells(3, i) + Base.Cells(10, i)
    ElseIf Base.Cells(10, i - 1) <= 0 And Base.Cells(10, i) > 0 Then 'Roxo
        Base.Cells(11, i) = Base.Cells(10, i) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Base.Range(Base.Cells(11, 2), Base.Cells(11, i - 1)), Base.Cells(3, i)) 'O máximo é um valor histórico ou o baseline do ano
    ElseIf Base.Cells(10, i - 1) <= 0 And Base.Cells(10, i) < 0 Then 'Azul
        Base.Cells(11, i) = Base.Cells(11, i - 1) + Base.Cells(10, i)
    ElseIf Base.Cells(10, i) = 0 And Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Base.Range(Base.Cells(10, 2), Base.Cells(10, i - 1))) <> 0 Then 'Rosa
        Base.Cells(11, i) = Base.Cells(3, i)
    ElseIf Base.Cells(10, i) > 0 And Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Base.Range(Base.Cells(10, 2), Base.Cells(10, i - 1))) = 0 Then 'Vermelho
        Base.Cells(11, i) = Base.Cells(3, i) + Base.Cells(10, i)
    ElseIf Base.Cells(10, i) < 0 And Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Base.Range(Base.Cells(10, 2), Base.Cells(10, i - 1))) = 0 Then 'Verde Claro
        Base.Cells(11, i) = Base.Cells(10, i)
    End If
Next i

'Série SOCIAL: Preenche valor referente ao ano de nascimento
If Base.[b7] = 0 Then
    Base.[b8] = 0
Else
    Base.[b8] = Base.[7]
End If

'Série SOCIAL: preenche demais anos (Planilha Ref, oculta)
For i = 3 To Idade + 2
    If Base.Cells(7, i - 1) >= 0 And Base.Cells(7, i) > 0 Then 'Laranja
        Base.Cells(8, i) = Base.Cells(8, i - 1) + Base.Cells(7, i)
    ElseIf Base.Cells(7, i - 1) >= 0 And Base.Cells(7, i) < 0 Then 'verde água
        Base.Cells(8, i) = Base.Cells(7, i)
    ElseIf Base.Cells(7, i - 1) < 0 And Base.Cells(7, i) > 0 Then 'Roxo
        Base.Cells(8, i) = Base.Cells(7, i)
    ElseIf Base.Cells(7, i - 1) < 0 And Base.Cells(7, i) < 0 Then 'Azul
        Base.Cells(8, i) = Base.Cells(7, i)
    ElseIf Base.Cells(7, i) = 0 Then 'Rosa
        Base.Cells(8, i) = 0
    End If
Next i

'Ajusta a fonte de dados do gráfico
With Charts("Meu Grafico")
.SeriesCollection(1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SERIES(BASE!R5C1,BASE!R2C2:R2C" & Coluna & ",BASE!R5C2:R5C" & Coluna & ",1)"  'Pessoal
.SeriesCollection(2).FormulaR1C1 = "=SERIES(BASE!R8C1,BASE!R2C2:R2C" & Coluna & ",BASE!R8C2:R8C" & Coluna & ",2)" 'Social
.SeriesCollection(3).FormulaR1C1 = "=SERIES(BASE!R11C1,BASE!R2C2:R2C" & Coluna & ",BASE!R11C2:R11C" & Coluna & ",3)" 'Profissional
.SeriesCollection(4).FormulaR1C1 = "=SERIES(BASE!R3C1,BASE!R2C2:R2C" & Coluna & ",BASE!R3C2:R3C" & Coluna & ",4)" 'Série 4 (Baseline)
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Which version of Mac Excel are you using?

Comment: Excel 2016, Cindy.